# Use Eval with vice versa mode in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, eval

Normal usage of `Eval` function is like:

```
ValueName2 = Eval("Value" + CStr(CurrentValue) + "Name2")
```

This can return `Value[n]Name2` according to `CurrentValue`.

Then how I tried to use `Eval` in vice versa mode:

```
Eval("Value" + CStr(CurrentValue) + "Name2") = ValueName2
```

So this can always return `ValueName2` no matter if original variable (Eg:`Value1Name2`,`,Value100Name2`.....).

But, this time when I check values of `Value1Name2`, it is empty and VB Script also return an error:

> Type mismatch: "Eval"

Then how can I use `Eval` in vice versa mode?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I do not think you can use `Eval` this way. Use **`Regex`** or **`Split`**. Much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Eval` will always return a value, not a variable reference, so, you can not use `Eval` to solve the problem.

You can use

```
Call Execute( "Value" + CStr(CurrentValue) + "Name2 = ValueName2" )
```

But it is easier and faster to use an array or a dictionary.